# PHP 403 Forbidden on Redirect

Tags: php, http-status-code-403

I have a weird one. I have written some code where my script adds something into the database, then after successfully adding it, the page is redirected to the homepage, with some cookies that get set to let the customer know it has been successfully added. Everything was working fine, but then the other day, all of a sudden my client gets a "403 Forbidden - Server configuration does not allow access to this page." error. If you refresh the page however, it loads fine. It only seems to be on the redirect that it happens.

As mentioned, everything seemed to be working fine until a few days ago.

Any ideas? I can supply some code if necessary.

Thanks

Comment: I also forgot to mention that the problem isn't reproducible on localhost, only on the hosting server.

Comment: Is the url the same before and after refreshing the page? Are you sure it is not a typo?

Comment: It's happening in 2 places. Once on the same page, and once coming from a different page.. I've isolated the problem however. I was trying to pass a <form method="post">....</form> through the cookie so the client could quickly redeem a second time on the home page. When I removed that, it wasn't throwing the 403 anymore. Anyone know if this is possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've isolated the problem. I was trying to pass a .... within a string that i was saving and passing through a cookie so the client could quickly redeem a second time on the home page. When I removed that, it wasn't throwing the 403 anymore.